# Running the URL to clear cache gives blank page in Pentaho

Tags: caching, pentaho, mondrian, pentaho-cde, xaction

I am using Pentaho CDE. I am trying to clear the cache using the following URL. When I run it in the browser it doesn't give an error but shows a blank page. What can be the cause for this?

```
 http://localhost:8080/pentaho/ServiceAction?solution=admin&path=&action=clear_mondrian_schema_cache.xaction
```

"admin" in the URL refers to the folder in which the clear_mondrian_schema_cache.xaction file is found. What does "&action" in the URL refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, everyone knows that we can flush Mondrian cache manually.

**How**: Inside Pentaho User Console, Tools -> Refresh -> Mondrian Schema Cache. After few moments, *if everything is right* we get message: 'Mondrian Schema Cache Flushed Successfully'.

**Ok, what was done down there?** 'Mondrian Schema Cache Flushed Successfully' is predefined string for English locale if request returns code 200 (OK). According to this we know that click on it is calling some HTTP request method.

**What and where?** I'm using *Live HTTP Headers* plugin in Google Chrome browser. It tells me that PUC is calling:

1. GET /pentaho/api/mantle/isAuthenticated (and if response is OK?)
2. GET /pentaho/api/system/refresh/mondrianSchemaCache

If second request return code 200 (OK), PUC write message.

You can try it in your browser: **hostname:port/pentaho/api/system/refresh/mondrianSchemaCache**
It will clear your schema cache and stay blank page. If you want message, you can write script to collect response from HTTP request.